# How to update a WalletItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How do I update a [WalletItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.walletitem.aspx)? I can delete and then add a `WalletItem` but when I do, the tile for the `WalletItem` disappears from the start screen and I think other bad things happen as well.

How do I update a `WalletItem` without removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UpdateAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.walletitemstore.updateasync.aspx) method of your store.

The secret for why this works is that when you get a ticket via [WalletItemStore.GetItemsAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn631322.aspx), the WalletItems have their `Id`'s set already. This is a read-only property. So when you send that WalletItems back via the [WalletItemStore.UpdateAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.walletitemstore.updateasync.aspx) method, the Store reads the Id from the WalletItem.

This seams a little bit strange for me at least since the [WalletItemStore.AddAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.wallet.walletitemstore.addasync.aspx) accepts the Id as an argument and not as a property of the item.

Example:

```
var newTicket = MyService.GetTicket();

var store = await WalletManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var currentTickets = await store.GetItemsAsync();            

if (currentTickets.Count(x => x.Id == newTicket.SerialNumber) == 1)
{
    // the ticket exist so let's update it

    // get the "old" ticket from the Wallet store
    var ticket = currentItems.First(x => x.Id == newTicket.SerialNumber);

    // update the "old" ticket with the updated information
    ticket.DisplayName = newTicket.Name;
    ticket.BodyColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);

    // put the updated "old" ticket back in the store again
    await store.UpdateAsync(ticket);
}
else
{
    // the ticket does not exist so let's add it
    await store.AddAsync(newTicket.SerialNumber, new WalletItem(WalletItemKind.Ticket, newTicket.Name)
        {
            BodyFontColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255),
            BodyColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 50, 230),
            DisplayName = newTicket.Name,
            ExpirationDate = newTicket.ExpireDate,
            IssuerDisplayName = "My Company"
        });
}
```